# Understand PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false completly

Tags: php, pdo

**What I already know about `PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false`:**

1. You can bind on your own
2. If you do not bind, the parameter is automatically set back to `PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true`
3. `PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false` is a bit more secure
4. You should pay attention to whether you get false from the request with `PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false`

***So now my question, how do I look if false comes back and how do I deal with it and do I have to work with bind or is it enough to do Prepair and Execute?***

Here is my code, please also check whether it is correct by then.

```
<?php

$options= [
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbnam=db;charset=utf8', user, password, $options);

$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS ? FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute(); // Do I now have to check if the result is false?
```

Comment: Where did you read about "parameter is automatically set back to PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true" ? And what do you mean with "bind independently"? (And btw, no.4 is driver-dependent, not something that happens at random.)

Comment: @mario 'If the database server does not support prepared statements, PDO falls back on emulation. Say, even if you set it to false, your application will work.' thats what I read. And mean with "bind independently" that you can bind the "normal way". Like this comment say: 'Note the points made in this answer re prepared statement emulation using mysql_real_escape_string under the hood and the consequent vulnerabilities that can arise (in very particular edge cases).' In a PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES question.

Comment: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, max_bench, max_squat FROM myTable WHERE weight < ?");
$stmt->execute([200]);
` Is this like binding or do I have to bindParam() with PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false?

Comment: Not gonna happen in practice. Unless your mysql server got downgraded from v7 to v1 or something (in which case the lack of parameter binding shouldn't be the primary worry). -- So "normal way" refers to the tedious `→bindParam()` iteration? (You ought to know that `→execute([…])` very much does type binding implicitly). -- Sounds like you misinterpreted whatever that other question was about.

Comment: Ok so:
`$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, max_bench, max_squat FROM myTable WHERE weight < ?");
$stmt->execute([$int]);`
AND
`$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, max_bench, max_squat FROM myTable WHERE weight < ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $int, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();`
does the same in case of `PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false` and also is same secure?

Comment: What do you mean *"how do I look if false comes back"*?

Comment: @Dharman there is an obscure case, when you provide more values than parameters in the query, it can silently fail. Given it can happen only at the development phase. I don't think it's worth such a verification

Comment: @Dharman also, given Nikita is [working/worked on PDO lately](https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/keyog2/consider_using_fetchall_instead_of_fetchall/gg5uv28/), I hope it will be fixed/put straight/converted into exception as well

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's not an obscure case, it's a bug. Such things should be reported or even better create a PR to fix it. The bug you mentioned has been fixed in PHP 8.0 already but if there ever is a scenario that an exception is not thrown but should be then it's a bug. Thankfully Nikita picked up the PDO/mysqlnd and fixed a lot recently, but there is still demand for C developers to fix more bugs.

Comment: Does that mean you do it the exect same way with `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false` on `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true` just that `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false` is safer?

Comment: @user14850460 Yes, that is the whole point. However, bear in mind that prior to PHP 8.1 the `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true` has a number of bugs. It is always recommended to disable emulated prepares. You can read more about it here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. You can bind on your own

EMULATE_PREPARES applies to both `→bindParam` and `→execute` likewise.

> 2. If you do not bind, the parameter is automatically set back to PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true

No. The PDO setting has no influence on manually interpolated tidbits. If that's what "not bind" was supposed to mean.

If EMULATE_PREPARES was enabled, it applied to any bound parameter. Per default it typecasts any input to strings, escapes it, and interpolates it as `'$escaped_str'` in place of the placeholder.

The difference is that execute() interprets all parameters as strings per default, whereas bindParam can typecast and interpolate integers/floats as literals.

I have a feeling this question is based on the assumption that more long-winded code improves security. It doesn't. The only reason to use `→bindParam` in either case is to work around the lack of typecasting on some MySQL query contexts (such as the LIMIT clause). (Albeit `LIMIT 1*?, 1*?` is often the better workaround there.)

> 3. PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false is a bit more secure

Sure.

> 4. You should pay attention to whether you get false from the request with PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false

Not gonna happen in reality. The support for emulation is driver-dependent. It's not going to change at runtime for the same database driver and database server.

And you can't really check it, since EMULATE_PREPARES is a initialization option, not something that you usually adapt per [`PDO::setAttribute`](http://php.net/PDOStatement-setAttribute) in between queries.

> Ok so: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, max_bench, max_squat FROM myTable WHERE weight < ?"); $stmt->execute([$int]);` AND `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, max_bench, max_squat FROM myTable WHERE weight < ?"); $stmt->bindParam(1, $int, PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->execute();` does the same with PDO :: ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false and also is same secure?

It's mostly the same, if `$int` was an integer already. `bindParam()` only does a secondary typecast, if need be. Irrelevant since MySQL would do the same on its end anyway, depending on the target columns type.

Comment: Not entirely true *"The support for emulation is driver-dependent. It's not going to change at runtime for the same database driver and database server"* Some SQL queries cannot be prepared and will fallback to emulation. See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_mysql/tests/bug70066.phpt

Comment: Does that mean you do it the exect same way with `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false` on `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true` just that `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false` is safer?